# Java Algorithm for All subsets of an array(having integer numbers) satisfying the sum?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I am working on java program , which gives you all possible sets numbers of an array which contributes to the given sum.

**e.g.** `we have an Array of numbers {1,2,2,3,4,5} these might be unsorted`

**possible subsets/output for sum "5" are**  :  `{1,2,2} {3,2} {4,1} & {5}`

Solution wrote by me does not serve the purpose , Can some one please help here and point out whats wrong in algorithm or is there any other better way of solution.

Thanks in advance.

Code Below :

```
public static List<List<Integer>> possibleCombinations(int[] array,
    int requiredSum) {
Arrays.sort(array);
List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
HashSet<String> hello = new HashSet<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] > requiredSum) {
        break;
    } else if (array[i] == requiredSum) {
        List<Integer> single = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        single.add(requiredSum);
        result.add(single);
        return result;
    }
    for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
        if (array[j] > requiredSum) {
            break;
        } else if (array[j] == requiredSum) {
            List<Integer> single = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            single.add(requiredSum);
            result.add(single);
            return result;
        }
        List<Integer> possibility = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        possibility.add(array[i]);
        int sum = 0;
        sum += array[i];
        for (int k = j; k < array.length; k++) {
            if ((sum + array[k]) < requiredSum) {
                possibility.add(array[k]);
                sum += array[k];
            } else if (sum + array[k] == requiredSum) {
                possibility.add(array[k]);
                result.add(possibility);
                break;
            } else {
                if(possibility.isEmpty() || possibility.size()==1){
                    break;
                }
                sum -= possibility.get(possibility.size() - 1);
                possibility.remove(possibility.size() - 1);
                k--;
                continue;
            }
        }

    }
}

return result;
```

}

Comment: That's not how this site works.

Comment: we are not here to do your work and follow you command.

Comment: I know one with a polynomial run-time!

Comment: @RamPrakash I am seeking help and not commanding any one ,Please see the below solution I have tried so far.

Comment: @ChrisGong please find the code I have been writing so far, but does not work in all the cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it can help you.
I didnt compile the code, but I'm pretty sure it will works.

It works with complexity O(2^N), where N is the number of elements.

```
void printSubsetSum(int []nums,int targetSum) {
    int n = nums.length;

    // generate all possible combination from binary representation
    for(int mask=(1<<n)-1;mask>0;mask--) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        // check by bit operation
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            // if ith bit is on then we add our candidate number
            if((mask & (1<<i))!=0) list.add(nums[i]);
        }

        // sum all element in list
        int sum = 0;
        for(int x:list) sum += x;

        // if the sum equals targetSum then we print our list
        if(sum==targetSum) System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

**How My Solution Works**

Assume we have the test input {1,2,2,3,4,5}

There are 6 number and we want to find every combination for sum = 5.

My solution works by generate binary number from (2^6 - 1) until 1.

```
63 = 111111
62 = 111110
61 = 111101
..
3  = 000011
2  = 000010
1  = 000001
```

For every 1 in binary number position, I pick the value from testinput and sum it.

Example:

```
101101 from {1,2,2,3,4,5} that means 1 + 2 + 3 + 5.
000101 from {1,2,2,3,4,5} that means 3 + 5.
```

Comment: It Works very well , Thanks for the solution

Comment: @algojava  could you please explain how this solution works.

Comment: @hemant: sure, I will edit my answer

Comment: @algojava . I got it thanks for solution. Is there is another way to reduce the ploynomial complexity like DP.

Comment: @hemant: in this case, we want to print every combination. So 2^n solution is the best. If we only want to find 1 valid solution then we can use DP with complexity O(n * sum).

Comment: @algojava thanks for the solution, works like a charm. I am also working on a solution(depends on this I hope) which is best fit in a bucket detailed description in below comment:

Comment: Lets say we have below numbers in an array {1,2,3,2,4,5} and we want to fit in buckets (i.e sum) of capacity 5 ,6 and 6 respectively. Ideal solution for this would be as for 5={5} and 6={1,3,2} and 6 ={4,2} , lets say if we pick 5={1,2,2}  remaining elements are {3,4,5} which does not fit in the remaining two buckets of holding capacity of 6, and does not seem to be best fit solution , So to get Ideal solution I would use solution suggested by you to find possible arangements and then again using these arrangements for best fit solution. Could you please advise if approach looks fine ?

Answer (score 0):

I have written below algorithm , but does not work in all the cases , it only prints subsequent arrangements of subsets.

```
public static List<List<Integer>> possibleCombinations(int[] array,
        int requiredSum) {
    Arrays.sort(array);
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    HashSet<String> hello = new HashSet<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > requiredSum) {
            break;
        } else if (array[i] == requiredSum) {
            List<Integer> single = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            single.add(requiredSum);
            result.add(single);
            return result;
        }
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[j] > requiredSum) {
                break;
            } else if (array[j] == requiredSum) {
                List<Integer> single = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                single.add(requiredSum);
                result.add(single);
                return result;
            }
            List<Integer> possibility = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            possibility.add(array[i]);
            int sum = 0;
            sum += array[i];
            for (int k = j; k < array.length; k++) {
                if ((sum + array[k]) < requiredSum) {
                    possibility.add(array[k]);
                    sum += array[k];
                } else if (sum + array[k] == requiredSum) {
                    possibility.add(array[k]);
                    result.add(possibility);
                    break;
                } else {
                    if(possibility.isEmpty() || possibility.size()==1){
                        break;
                    }
                    sum -= possibility.get(possibility.size() - 1);
                    possibility.remove(possibility.size() - 1);
                    k--;
                    continue;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: can you explain how it works?

Comment: @hemant it runs in complexity O(n3), and also wont run for all the cases, Solution advised by algojava is better